# Allow a method to get either an Enum or its sub Enum

Tags: java

Got the following enumerator:

```
public enum Movement {
  FORWARD;

  @AllArgsConstructor
  public enum Turn {
    RIGHT(90),
    LEFT(-90);

    @Getter private final int degrees;
  }
}
```

and I got a method that needs to take as parameter an element of type *Movement*, hence FORWARD, along with its inner enumerator *Turn* (Turn.RIGHT and Turn.LEFT).
Here is the current method that only works with FORWARD:

```
private Diary.Record buildDiaryRecord(Movement movement) {
    return Diary.Record.builder()
        .timestamp(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()))
        .currentLocation(currentLocation)
        .direction(getCompass().getDirection())
        .action(movement)
        .build();
  }
```

if I try to do this:

```
 public void turn(Movement.Turn turn) {
    diary.getRecords().push(buildDiaryRecord(turn));
  }
```

Correctly I got a compilation error.

Hence my question is: how to make this method generic enough to accept Turn as well?

Comment: `Movement` and `Turn` are completely unrelated, except for the shared location, namespace, and privileged access that ensues. The quickest answer is that you can make them implement the same interface... but before you do that, you have to answer the question why they are two different enums at all. If they have to be different, what makes them so similar that you expect to be able to use them in an uniform way? Maybe the latter question will guide your design of a common interface, but you may also be able to avoid that altogether.

Comment: Think I got you point @ernest_k